# How to filter everything between two chars in charbuffer?

Tags: java

I'm reading portions of a big file into a `char[]` buffer. I want to postprocess this buffer (means: extract everything that is contained within two quotes), and then write the remaining part to a new file.

sample.txt:

```
this is my "sample" string;
this is "another;
sample "finished;
```

Desired output:

```
this is my  string;
this is finished;
```

Code

```
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("sample.txt"))) {
    BufferedWriter writer;
    char[] buffer = new char[1024 * 1024 * 128];

    int cnt = 0;
    while ((cnt = br.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        //TODO in a for or while loop?
        writer.write(buffer, index, len);
    }
}
```

Question: how can I now find the indexes, so that I can write out anything before and after those indexes?

Important is that the buffer may even contain no quotes. In those cases, it must be evaluated if the buffer before contained an open or closing quote, and depending on this write or neglect the current buffer.

Sidenote: for performance reasons (100GB file), I want to avoid having to convert the content to `Strings` first before writing them out. So anything like `reader.readLine()` which converts to `String` should be avoided. I benchmarked this of course and found out that reading using this `charbuffer` is twice as good as using eg `reader.readLine()` which is due to string conversation! Same applies to `Scanner`.

So why do I think there is room for a quicker approach?

Because writing my file out as follows is 3x faster than reading with `bufferedReader.readLine())`:

```
int cnt = 0;
while ((cnt = br.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    writer.write(buffer, 0, cnt);
}
```

So this simply writes input to output without filter.
The question is, how can I filter out the quoted text with charbuffer?

Comment: The line are lines, but that's not important. I also want to remove content if the opening and closing quote spreads over multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the simplest possible loop (which does spin pretty hot, but let's hope it gets optimized by JIT)?

```
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("sample.txt"))) {
    int c;
    boolean inQuotes = false;

    while ((c = br.read()) != -1) {
        if(c == '"')
            inQuotes = !inQuotes;
        else if(!inQuotes)
            writer.write(c);
    }
}
```

If you don't need multi-byte charset support, you can use `BufferedInput/OutputStream` instead, which will avoid `byte -> char -> byte` conversion overhead.

Comment: While this looks promising, I don't get it. c is the number if of bytes read into the buffer, so how could this be equal to a quote?

Comment: @membersound that was a typo, there is no buffer except the internal buffers in the reader and writer.

Comment: Unfortunately this is worse than just using `BufferedReader.readLine()`, although only a bit. But not faster. Tried also `BufferedInputStream` without success.

Comment: Well I don't believe that. Using raw bytes means there's a lot of overhead gone, it should be faster than using `readLine()`. Either you're measuring things wrong, or the root issue is somewhere else.

Comment: My test is simple: filesize about 2GB. For performance testing I'm applying no filter at all: `br.lines().forEach(line -> writer.write(line + "\n"));` takes 20s, your solution takes almost 30s, and `writer.write(buffer, 0, cnt);` using the charbuffer takes 7s.

Comment: @membersound so you're not testing filtering, you're testing file copying. I think we're done here.

Comment: Well before I can test the filter, I should find the method that can copy my file as fast as possible? Because applying the filter will last longer, shouldn't I?

Comment: Of course not. If you want to achieve X, you test X. Now you're asking for solutions to X, but then you're testing Y. No wonder you're still stuck on this, your whole approach is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can tolerate materializing the entire text file in Java memory, you can just use a single one-liner regex replacement to strip off quoted terms:

```
String content = readFile("sample.txt", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
content = content.replaceAll("(?s)\".*?\"", "");
Files.write(Paths.get("sample.txt"), content.getBytes());
```

If you can't do this, and need to read line by line, then you'll have to implement your own parsing logic to know when a double quoted term begins, and when it ends.

Comment: preferably I want to prevent using classes that first read the content into a string, and then have to convert them back during file write. that's why I'm trying the `charbuffer` approach.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off using [StreamTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html), with `quoteChar('"')`. The class is a bit old and archaic, but it does allow you to stream the file, and handles the tokenization for you (I guess `Scanner` can handle this too, but this might have some performance benefits).

The code would be something like the following (probably requires fine tuning / additional config).

```
try(StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(myBufferedReader)) {

    st.quoteChar('"');

    while(st.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
        if(st.ttype == '"')
            continue;

        if(st.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD) {
            output.write(streamTokenizer.sval);
        } else if(st.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL) {
            output.newLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: preferably I want to prevent using classes that first read the content into a string, and then have to convert them back during file write.

Comment: @membersound I give answers based on what I believe to be best the solution. You're of course free to write complicated parsing logic if you want, but I doubt you need to. You haven't even tried this solution, but you're assuming it has bad performance. Bad mistake. Performance is measured, not assumed or guessed.

Comment: I have tried different solutions involving readers that convert lines to strings first, like `bufferedReader.readLine()`. Performance is 2x worse then just using a char buffer that is written out. Of course I also tested your example, but some problem with the strings here.

Comment: @membersound in your previous questions you haven't indicated that you want to filter out strings between quotes, so people have given you answers with `readLine()` etc. you ask basically the same question multiple times, but you add a bit of detail in each one to make the previous solutions incompatible. You're hard to help.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just trying to update the question based on the answers I got, and added the details that I probably missed for my problem. No bad intend here.

Comment: @membersound do you need to support multi-byte characters?